# Bootstrap Column Width Ratios

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4, css-grid

The Bootstrap grid system is of course 12 columns.

I want to have and use all the 12 columns across the page.

But I want the first 6 left-hand columns to be half the width (i.e 50%) of the right-hand columns width.

So that the right 6 column will always be double width of the ones on the left.

This width ratio should remain across changing page/window resizing.

How can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This task is not for a boostrap grid system. 12 parts mean 12 equal width parts. And you want not equal 12 block. This is a task for `display: grid;`.

`grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 2fr) repeat(6, 1fr);` this part means that we take 6 times for `2fr` and then 6 times for `1fr`. `fr` is a new measure for `grid`. It means all grid is devides on a sum all `fr`s in one row. So `2fr` is a block twice bigger then `1fr`. In our case we have `2fr 2fr 2fr 2fr 2fr 2fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr` = 18 parts in a row. It's just for you to know hove does `fr` works.

Links for some CSS Grid documentation:

- [Basic Concepts of grid layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout)
- [grid-template-columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns)

```css
.grid-row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 2fr) repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  grid-row-gap: .5rem;
  grid-column-gap: .5rem;
}

.grid-col {
  background: #000;
  min-height: 50px;
}

/* example of adaptivity for smaller screens */
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .grid-row {  
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 2fr) repeat(3, 1fr);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-row">
  <div class="grid-col"></div>
  <div class="grid-col"></div>
  <div class="grid-col"></div>
  <div class="grid-col"></div>
  <div class="grid-col"></div>
  <div class="grid-col"></div>
  <div class="grid-col"></div>
  <div class="grid-col"></div>
  <div class="grid-col"></div>
  <div class="grid-col"></div>
  <div class="grid-col"></div>
  <div class="grid-col"></div>
</div>
```

Not sure, but if you want not twice, but 1.5 times wider cols, use next one. Updated only `grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 3fr) repeat(6, 2fr);`

```css
.grid-row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 3fr) repeat(6, 2fr);
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  grid-row-gap: .5rem;
  grid-column-gap: .5rem;
}

.grid-col {
  background: #000;
  min-height: 50px;
}

/* example of adaptivity for smaller screens */
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .grid-row {  
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 3fr) repeat(3, 2fr);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-row">
  <div class="grid-col"></div>
  <div class="grid-col"></div>
  <div class="grid-col"></div>
  <div class="grid-col"></div>
  <div class="grid-col"></div>
  <div class="grid-col"></div>
  <div class="grid-col"></div>
  <div class="grid-col"></div>
  <div class="grid-col"></div>
  <div class="grid-col"></div>
  <div class="grid-col"></div>
  <div class="grid-col"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks. Reference links also very useful.